# inline-block in IE9 compatibility quirks mode

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, quirks-mode

I am currently developing a html/css menu. My issue is that the page that the menu will be inserted in, when loaded, causes the browser to go into quirks and compatibility mode. I cannot control this.

Here is my css:

```
.community-menu {    
    margin: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 15px 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#container {
    width: 100%; 
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}
```

My issue is that inline-block in IE quirks and compatibility mode causes the menus to take up full width of its parent div.

Here is what the divs look like in Chrome and Firefox:

[image: Chrome and Firefox rendering of inline-block]

In IE the same divs expand to full width of parent div

[image: IE rendering of inline-block]

What I am trying to achieve is centred divs that resize with text contents that as the browser resizes are automatically pushed down.

I found some code from another SO question that shows my issue [here](http://jsfiddle.net/3sK4S/) when viewed with IE in compatibility and quirks mode.

Following a comment by Spudley here is a pic to show the default mode it loads in.

[image]

Even though it says IE8, the end result is the same in IE9. On different pc today :)

Comment: Could you post a working example? The HTML would be handy.

Comment: The problem with IE is that quirks mode uses an older rendering engine, which does not know about things like `inline-block`. There is no way around that. Why can you not use standards compliance mode?

Comment: You _can_ control IE compatibility mode. Add `X-UA-Compatible: IE=edge` HTTP response header to your server settings, or add `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />` element to deny  switching to compatibility-view mode.

Comment: My code is to be added to a webpage over which I have no control. I also have no control over the http headers sent with the response.

Comment: But how will you be adding the code then? Surely if you're able to add stuff, you can add meta elements or a DOCTYPE declaration?

Comment: @MrLister I have no control over the webpage as it is dynamically generated by a CMS and the doctype declaration is already defined. I am adding code to a section of the webpage. Would it be possible to override the doctype by adding a `X-UA-Compatible` meta element in the body?

Comment: You can't override the DOCTYPE declaration, but if you're really desperate, you could try if putting a meta element in the body has any effect. Good luck.

Comment: Quirks mode is a compatibility mode for emulating IE5. (Yes, IE5. Have you any idea how old that is?) This means it is missing a *ton* of features, which in turn means that you're going to really struggle to get modern web code working with it. `inline-block` will be the least of your problems; there are far worse things than that in Quirks mode. Also, Quirks mode should only come into play at all if the doctype is missing or invalid. If you have a doctype there and still going into quirks mode then you may have bigger problems to deal with than just dealing with missing features.

Comment: Also, to clarify: "Quirks mode" and "Compatibility mode" are entirely different things. There is no "compatiblity quirks mode". They're all bad, but quirks mode is orders of magnitude worse. It would be really helpful if you could edit the question to be clear about which mode IE is actually in. It would help us to help you if we knew. (to find out for certain, press F12 in IE while you're in the page, and look at the mode info in the dev tools window, top right).

Comment: @Spudley Thanks for that. Very informative. Do you know if it is possible to inject the doctype declaration or is it something that cannot be changed?

Comment: @Bruno - it can't be manipluated in Javascript as (1) it is outside of the DOM, and (2) it needs to be specified on page load when the browser decides what mode to use. It would need to be changed in your server-side code; ie in the CMS. However I would add that the problem is likely in your page template rather than in the CMS itself; it's likely to be a very easy thing to fix.

Comment: By the way: thanks for the mode screenshot; that is helpful. The first part (the Browser mode) represents how the browser is identifying itself to the server -- ie in this case it is telling the server that it is IE8 via the User Agent string. The second part (Document mode) is the mode that is used to do the page rendering. In this case, it is quirks mode, which means that your doctype is broken or missing. (If you have a doctype, it may be because you have some blank space or other content in the page before it; that can cause IE to ignore the doctype)

Comment: Also, you might like to read [my blog post on this topic](http://spudley.com/blog/keeping-ie-in-standards-mode); it's got more info than I can really cover here in the comments.

Answer (score 2):

"display: inline-block;" better to change on:
    {
    float:left|right;
    diplay:inline;
    zoom:1;
    }

Answer (score 0):

When i need to emulate inline-block in olds and quirks IE, i just replace inline-block by inline.
(With conditionnal comment)

Comment: I thought about this, however when I use an inline declaration the margin and padding declarations are ignored and as a result the menu elements overlap when jumping onto a new line.